# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function, button inside form

Tags: javascript, forms, exception, button

I have the following snippet of code in my jsp page:

```
<form name="programarRutasForm" method="post" action="/SGT_Galp_web/programarRutas.do">   
     <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="button" name="insereVuelta" value="Insere Vuelta" onclick="insereVuelta()" id="insereVuelta">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" name="criaRuta" value="Cria Ruta" id="criaRuta">
          </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
     ...
```

When I click the button `insereVuelta`, it throws an exception with the message:

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

But if I put the button outside the form it works normally. How is this happening? I really need to put the button near the submit button inside the form.

Comment: It would really help if you provide the insereVuelta() function so we wouldn't have to guess where the error is.

Comment: Most likely I bet you're defining the function inside of another function and therefore it doesn't exist in the global scope. Or you are spelling it wrong.

Comment: If that was the problem , it will never work with the button outside the form, but thanks by the help

Answer (score 8):

I believe the problem stems from the function having the same name as the button itself. I had the same problem and changing the name of the button fixed it. It looks like changing the name of your button fixed it for you, as well.

Conjecture:

I would guess that when the names are the same, the interpreter is trying to call the button itself, rather than the function. Because the button isn't a function, it throws the error.

I don't have an explanation for why it worked for you when outside the form, though. Perhaps when a button is outside the form, the interpreter doesn't automatically wire it up as an accessible object in the same way, or maybe it would have to be accessed via a "parent".

Answer (score 0):

The Error is because of problems with Semi-colons. Check if your script has lines that are missing semi-colons. You would ask "then why does it work outside the form?" The Automatic-Semicolon insertion fails in certain situations; you can read about it more here:
[What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion)

I feel this would solve the problem.

Comment: I already fix the problem but i still do not know i it fails, the only thing i did was change the name attribute to "insertVueltaButton".Thanks by the quick answer :)

Answer (score 0):

insereVuelta is used as the name and id of the input and the name of the function, try changing name and id or the function name.