# JS/jQuery event.submit/return true not woking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am wondering if someone can help me as i cant figure this out. I have this validation script that checks an email form for contents and valid email and it is working correctly however it is not submitting the form if everything is okay..it just removes to error messages and does nothing.

I have a strange feeling it will be something stupid but i cant see anything wrong here.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include('includes/head.php'); ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/contactVal.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include('includes/navbar.php'); ?>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
                    <p>Use this handy little contact form to get in contact with me about anything at all. If you have a job offer or any questions about me then feel free to drop me a message, ill get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
                    <hr>
                    <div id="form-response">
                    </div>
                    <form id="mailer" action="scripts/mailer.php" method="POST">
                        <h3>Name:</h3>
                        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name"></input><br />

                        <h3>Email:</h3>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address"></input><br />

                        <h3>Subject:</h3>
                        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Enter the subject of your message"></input><br />

                        <h3>Message:</h3>
                        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Enter your message here..."></textarea><br />

                        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send"></input><br /><br />

                        <input type="hidden" name="honeypot" id="honeypot" value="http://" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="human" id="human" value="" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3>Details</h3>
                    <p><img class="about-arrow" src="img/icons/arrow.png" />Email: contact@alexvolley.co.uk</p>
                    <p><img class="about-arrow" src="img/icons/arrow.png" />Website: www.alexvolley.co.uk</p>
                    <p><img class="about-arrow" src="img/icons/arrow.png" />Mobile: On request</p>
                    <hr>
                    <h3>Socials</h3>
                    <a class="big" href="http://www.facebook.com/oukp3ngu1nx"><img class="about-arrow" src="img/icons/arrow.png" />Facebook</a><br />
                    <a class="big" href="http://www.twitter.com/alex_volley_"><img class="about-arrow" src="img/icons/arrow.png" />Twitter</a><br />
                    <a class="big" href="https://www.linkedin.com/pub/alex-volley/97/27/906"><img class="about-arrow" src="img/icons/arrow.png" />LinkedIn</a><br />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php include('includes/footer.php'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form-response').hide();
    $('#form-response').click(function(){
        $('#form-response').fadeOut();
    });
    $('#submit').click(function(){

        event.preventDefault();

        var valid = '';
        var name = $('form #name').val();
        var email = $('form #email').val();
        var subject = $('form #subject').val();
        var message = $('form #message').val();
        var honey = $('form #honeypot').val();
        var human = $('form #human').val();
        var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

        //check for human interaction
        if(honey == 'http://' && human == ""){
            //check fields
            if(name == '' || null || name.length < 2){
                valid = '<p>You need to enter your name.</p>';
            }

            if(email == '' || null || email.length < 5){
                valid += '<p>You need to enter an email address.</p>';   
            }

            if(!email.match(filter)){
                valid += '<p>You need to enter a valid email address.</p>';   
            }

            if(subject == '' || null || subject.length < 2){
                valid += '<p>You need to enter a valid subject.</p>';   
            }

            if(message == '' || null || message.length < 30){
                valid += '<p>You need to enter a message of at least 30 characters.</p>';   
            }

            //check if valid
            if(valid != ''){
                $('#form-response').removeClass().addClass('error').html('<h3>There was a few problems..</h3>' + valid).fadeIn('slow');
            } else {
                $('#form-response').fadeOut('slow');
                $('#form-response').hide();
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            //spambot
            error = '<p>Back of bot boy.</p>';
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Since you used `preventDefault()`, it doesn't matter what you return.

Comment: ^ what Barmar said, you could return unicorns, but it won't matter as you've already prevented the default action. I'd suggest using the native submit handler and doing `this.form.submit()` when valid.

Comment: would there be an alternative way to prevent the form from sending that you could recommend then?

i just trued this.form.submit() by the way and that didn't seem to make it submit :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not pass `event` in the `function` arguments:

```
$('#submit').click(function( event ){

    event.preventDefault();
```

You're probably better off using the `submit` event and letting the submit button do it's job:

```
$('#mailer').submit(function( event ){

    event.preventDefault();
    ........
    if(valid != ''){
            $('#form-response').removeClass().addClass('error').html('<h3>There was a few problems..</h3>' + valid).fadeIn('slow');
            this.submit(); //ONCE EVERYTHING CHECKS OUT
    } else {
    .....
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/6jZdG/)

**EDIT**

To resolve the error `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`, please change the name of your submit button to something else: `this.submit` -- the button, is conflicting with `this.submit()` -- the function.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/zUQ6T/1/) is a version that works fine after changing: `name="submit"` to `name="submit-button"`

By the way your `input` elements do not need a closing tag `</input>`

REF: [Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function, button inside form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488145/)

Comment: i have just tried this and when changing it to .submit it doesn't prevent the form from sending and just submits

Comment: yep, here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abs4f/ sorry that took so long.

also if you want a live version i have it up on here http://www.alexvolley.co.uk/contact

Comment: You have ` onclick="mailerVal();"` set on the submit button but you do not have the function `mailerVal()` defined in your code. `event.preventDefault()` cannot stop `onclick` from firing; neither can `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`.

Comment: ahhh, oops i changed it to a function last night to see if that would fix it, i have just taken off the onClick again but it still doesn't allow me to submit the form if everything is ok

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zUQ6T/

Comment: That's quite strange, isn't it? It throws the error `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function` on `this.submit()` or the equivalent `$('#mailer')[0].submit()` .... .... that should not happen. May be there's something we're not seeing. Best way to troubleshoot would be to start off with a 'bare bones' form and add onto it slowly to see where it breaks. What do you think?

Comment: DUDE your amazing, thankyou so much for you help with this. i never though about the submit conflicting with the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try following code. On Submit button click validate form and if everything is fine submit form using .submit method.

```
$('#submit').click(function( event ){

    event.preventDefault();
    ............
    if(valid != ''){
            $('#form-response').removeClass().addClass('error').html('<h3>There was a few problems..</h3>' + valid).fadeIn('slow');               
    } else {
      $('#form-response').fadeOut('slow');
      $('#form-response').hide();
      $('#mailer').submit(); //ONCE EVERYTHING CHECKS OUT
    }
   ..............
```

Comment: just tried this and it is still not submitting, it does the fadeout and hide of the form response but then doesn't do the submit

Comment: You have button name and id as submit which is causing JQuery error. Try this code as given in http://jsfiddle.net/5349r/

Comment: i have just tried this now and it never worked but got this in the console:

m.fn.init[1]
0: form#mailerForm
context: document
length: 1
selector: "#mailerForm"
__proto__: Object[0]